# How to tell whether the current function is a regular or a static member function in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, static, c-preprocessor, static-members

I'll try to explain what I'm trying to do:

```
bool if_filter_applies() {return true;}

#defile LOGFILE if( if_filter_applies() ) LOG_STREAM_OBJECT

void globalFunc() { LOGFILE << "Some data \n"; }

class C {
    int a;
    bool if_filter_applies() {
       if ( a == 1)
          return true;
       else
          return false;
       }
 public:
   void regMem () {
      LOGFILE << "Some data\n";
   }
   static void staticMem() {
      LOGFILE << "Some data\n";
   }
 };
```

I'm trying to modify a LOGFILE definition so that it ONLY writes to a stream when used from within a class's member function based on the output of the `if_filter_applies()` member function.

If LOGFILE is used from outside the class or in a static member function, I want it to use the Global `if_filter_applies()` function (which always returns true).

The above code does not compile, because `static void staticMem()` ends up using the `if_filter_applies()` class member instead of the global.

I don't want to create a different definition similar to `#define LOGFILE` as a replacement specifically for static member functions, because there are hundreds of files in our code and I don't want to replace all occurrences manually.

So are there any changes I can make to `#defile LOGFILE` macro so that it calls `::if_filter_applies()` instead in the context of a static member function?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25863485/is-it-possible-to-bring-global-function-into-the-overload-resolution-with-member?lq=1) (yes I'm equally disappointed)

Comment: Why would you want to **#defile** your LOGFILE :(

Comment: It is not really a log file for my use case, it is actually a circular buffer. I just made LOGFILE up to explain my problem. :)

Answer (score 3):

If you're using MS Visual Studio, you can use the [`__if_exists`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x7wy9xh3(v=vs.80).aspx) check against `this`.  So something like:

```
__if_exists(this)
{
    // In a member function
}
__if_not_exists(this)
{
    // Not in a member function
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, I'm not using MS Visual Studio. Are there other equivalents for "__if_exists"?

Comment: I see that clang has a [-fms-extensions](http://llvm.org/releases/3.0/docs/ClangReleaseNotes.html#windows) option...  could give that a try..

Comment: Thanks. Is there anything for linux systems?