# How to convert a template type to string if it can be a string too?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, templates

I have class:

```
template <typename val_t>
class tracer_t : public base_tracer_t<val_t> {
    std::vector<std::string> m_trace;
public:
    virtual void push_fact(val_t fact) override {
        std::string str = "+ fact: " + to_string(fact);
        m_trace.push_back(std::move(str));
    }

    virtual void push_rule(const std::string &id, val_t val, bool tg) override {
        std::string str = "+ ";
        if (tg) { str += "target: "; }
        else { str += "rule: "; }
        str += id + " -> " + to_string(val);
        m_trace.push_back(std::move(str));
    }

    virtual void print() override {
        std::cout << "Stack trace: " << std::endl;
        for (auto it = m_trace.begin(); it != m_trace.end(); ++it) {
            std::cout << (*it) << std::endl;
        }
    }
private:
    std::string to_string(val_t val) {
        if (std::is_same<val_t, std::string>::value) {
            return (std::string)val;
        }
        return std::to_string(val);
    }
};
```

The problem is that it doesn't compile if `val_t` is `std::string` because of:

```
tracer.hpp:49: error: no matching function for call to ‘to_string(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&)’
         return std::to_string(val);
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
```

But I can't get how to resolve it. I tried to check type manually but error is in compile time,so it didn't help

Comment: You can specialize the template (or a helper template) for `val_t = std::string`.

Comment: `std::to_string` doesnt allow a `std::string` arg - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just provide a new overload for `to_string`

```
std::string to_string(const std::string& s) { return s; }
```

You could put the code above inside the class, as a private method, or inside a suitable namespace, so to avoid possible clashes when, say, somebody uses your code and wishes to write her/his own overload of `to_string`.

EDIT: As noted in the comments below, you cannot put such an overload in the `std` namespace, as a new declaration of `std::to_string` is forbidden, see [Extending the namespace std](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std).

EDIT: If you need to possibly call `std::to_string`, you may need to add an additional `to_string` template function to your code as

```
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_convertible<T, std::string>::value, std::string>::type to_string(T r) const { return std::to_string(r); }
```

(Do not forget `#include <type_traits>` for that).

This is because, even if you import the standard library `std::to_string` by `using namespace std`, the member function `to_string` will have the priority. See the discussion: [C++: Why member function has priority over global function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25862633/c-why-member-function-has-priority-over-global-function). [Here](http://cpp.sh/9gek6) you can see a minimal example.

Comment: Overloading `std::to_string` is forbidden! At best you may specialize template functions in namespace `std`, but even that will go away in C++20.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Even if it's a member function?

Comment: @jrok That's fine, but then it's not `std::to_string` you're overloading.

Comment: @MaxLanghof As is the case here, no?

Comment: @MaxLanghof The answer clearly made a mistake and was intended to refer to a `to_string` function outside of `std`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thanks for the correction! I have added an explanation.

Comment: I got `error: call of overloaded ‘to_string(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&)’ is ambiguous`. Can you put sample, pls?

Comment: @MaxLanghof Thanks a lot for the comment. I have added an explanation with a relevant link to the reference.

Comment: @Шах See my addition: You cannot directly overload ```std::to_string```.

Comment: @francesco, but it says I can extend a standard library in C++ 20 only, I need C++ 11

Comment: @Шах not really. It says you can, in c++20, add a specialization of a *class template*. ```std::to_string``` is neither a class, nor a template function. This is why you have to add the code above inside the class, or inside a suitable namespace, not ```std```.

Comment: @francesco, I tried to add inside class to specify `to_string` realization for `const std::string &` type but it says `call of overloaded ‘to_string(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&)’ is ambiguous`. What am I doing wrong? Sorry, I'm a noobie in C++.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to specialize the entire class for `std::string` you could use `std::enable_if` or `if constexpr`(c++17)

```
auto to_string(val_t val)
    -> typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<val_t, std::string>::value, std::string>::type 
{
    return static_cast<std::string>(val);
}

auto to_string(val_t val)
    -> typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<val_t, std::string>::value, std::string>::type 
{
    return std::to_string(val);
}
```

Or the more modern approach, with `if constexpr`

```
auto to_string(val_t val)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same<val_t, std::string>::value)
    {
        return static_cast<std::string>(val);
    }
    else
    {
        return std::to_string(val);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can always specialize just this one function. :)

Comment: Soon, C++ will adopt Perl's slogan - TIMTIWTDI.

Comment: Why the `static_cast`? In fact I’d expect a compiler to warn about an unnecessary cast.

Comment: @KonradRudolph You are right, I just took the op's code and modified it, not considering the cast was unnecessary.

Comment: Sorry, it's my fault, I forgot to specify `c++11` tag. I am using 11 standard